# Unable to access FileNet CE from BAW

Tags: authentication, jaas, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, ibm-baw

I am unable to access FileNet CE from Java Service in BAW Process.

When we connect without a stanca, we get
"The user is not authenticated. There is no LoginModule associated with FileNetP8".

When we connect using stanca "FileNetP8WSI", we get
"Access to the Content Engine was not allowed because the Content Engine API library or the Web Service Interface (WSI) Listener could not find the required security context information. Expected credentials were not found in the security context."